# Minimizing square of positive function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Say I have a real valued function like

$$
f(x, y) = g(x, y)^2
$$

with

$$
g(x, y) \geq 0\quad \forall\, (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \,.
$$

Question: Is it correct that in order to minimize $f(x, y)$ I can as well minimize $g(x, y)$ and it will give me the same optimal $(x, y)$ values?

- If correct: Does this property/method have a special name?
- If not correct: Can someone provide a counterexample?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could say "by monotonicity of the quadratic function (on the non-negative real numbers)"

Comment: Does this mean the statement is correct? Why can I conclude from the monotonicity of the quadratic function that both $f$ and $g$ have the same minima?

Comment: Because $a\ge b \iff a^2\ge b^2$ when $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers. (One elementary proof is to look at $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, because $a < b \iff a^2 < b^2 \; \forall \;a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+_0$. This is because $f(x) = x^2$ is monotonic for non-negative numbers.

If $(x_0,y_0)$ is a global minimum of $g$, then let $(x, y)$ represent any other possible tuple other than $(x_0,y_0)$. We then have: $g(x_0,y_0) < g(x,y) \iff g(x_0,y_0)^2 < g(x,y)^2$ and the latter inequality is equivalent to $f(x_0,y_0) < f(x,y)$, making $(x_0,y_0)$ a minimum of $f$ as well. (The same logic applies in reverse: you could find a minimum of $f$ and you also have a minimum of $g$.)